# Bootstrap navbar link underline error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I typed following code. But i got underlined text. What is the my mistake? 
[image]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Hi</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: use text-decoration: none;

Comment: hmm. Other than that no bootstrap method?

Comment: i dont know other method wait for others reply

Comment: It doesn't show up in standard boostrap: http://www.bootply.com/bvfRXvae69 Check what stylings you have impacting the element with right-click `Inspect Element`

Comment: Bootstrap does not underline links. Something in your CSS, after the bootstrap, is doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text is actually a link (because it's in an `<a>` tag), and the CSS you are using probably says somewhere that links should be underlined. You can remove the underline by styling your link with this:

```
a.navbar-brand {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing the Bootstrap navbar uses the listelement to make a list of items like links to make a button in the navbar of it.

In your case:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Hi</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

would do the trick.

I set up a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7r20u4qh/) to show the result